# How to create a macro "environmentally-dependent"

Tags: macros, environments, conditionals, etoolbox

Yesterday I was reading the [`etoolbox` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) where there are defined some new document commands such as:

```
\Before<Begin/End>Environment{<envir>}{<code>}
%
\At<Begin/End>Environment{<envir>}{<code>}
%
\After<Begin/End>Environment{<envir>}{<code>}
```

Which I found very useful in dealing fine-tuning macro expansion inside or outside specific environments.

The main question however hit me when I wanted to define a new command, based on the above, that looks like this:

```
\If<Before/At/After><Begin/End>Environment{<envir>}{<code>}{%
 <yes>%
}{%
 <no>%
}
```

The main action of this code is that it checks if a specific control sequence name or macro/code `<code>` appears `<Before/At/After><Begin/End>` the `environment` and then applies the code if it is met the condition stated, and does else otherwise. This can be similar to the standard if-clause conditional very well known inside plain TeX (maybe some TeXpert could put an eye to this macro).

The main reason on why it reads the control sequence name it's that if there is some macro behind a specific environment, it doesn't expand its arguments and keeps reading it as a `csname`.

So my question can be expressed as: *how this macro can be created? is there some command that simulates its action that I'm not aware of?*

I basically couldn't find any documentation or source even remotely related to this application on macro setting.

Comment: Your listed commands are basically hacks of the commands `\begin` and `\end`. So you can put a simple if-clause inside the second mandatory argument of `\At<Begin/End>Environment{<envir>}{<code>}`.

Comment: The main problem could be like: I want to know if `\mymacro` is right before `listings`, but I do not know how this could be implemented. I'm saying this because if I'd do `\ifdefined\mymacro\else...` would be wrong because `\mymacro` is always defined.

Comment: You haven't defined what you mean by _before_ do you mean literally anywhere before a listings environment in the source, do you mean _immediately_ before (and how do you define immediately does white space or a blank line (\par) between them stop it being immedatiate) or do you mean "is this command being run from the before-hook of an enviornment added by the etoolbox package?"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm (trying) to say that the `<code>` inside `If<Before/At/After><Begin/End>Environment` has to be verified if it is immediately before/after my environment, without any `\par` that separates it. From your third option (I'm so sorry) I didn't understand well though.

Comment: What I mean is, because you introduced your question with `\Before<Begin/End>Environment{<envir>}{<code>}`  I would have assumed that you were asking how <code> could check that it was being run by that command in (for example) `\Before{listings}` but I don't think you mean that (so etoolbox probably isn't relevant to your question?)

Comment: You're right. `etoolbox`, as not that relevant, it's used because my command is very similar to `\Before<Begin/End>Environment{<envir>}{<code>}` (because mine is an if-clause conditional).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- the tag [tex-core] doesn't seem appropriate here, but i'm not sure what might be appropriate instead (if anything).  could you please edit the tags to be more accurate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\def\foo{\futurelet\tmp\xfoo}
\def\xfoo{\ifx\tmp\begin\expandafter\xxfoo\else\expandafter\nolistingsfoo\fi}
\def\xxfoo#1#2{\def\tmp{#2}%
  \ifx\tmp\xlistings\expandafter\listingsfoo\else\expandafter\nolistingsfoo\fi
  #1{#2}}
\def\xlistings{lstlisting}

\def\listingsfoo{\typeout{lstlisting is next}}
\def\nolistingsfoo{\typeout{lstlisting is not next}}

\begin{document}

\foo
\begin{lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}

\foo
\begin{center}
\end{center}

\foo xxxx
\begin{lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

produces

```
lstlisting is next
lstlisting is not next
lstlisting is not next
```

Comment: Too bad that double upvote doesn't exist :-), so now I could substitute accurately to obtain the needed code before the environment. OK so far, but what about (only for coherence) the after environment (just to inclue both cases)?

Comment: well basically you can't check backwards. You could redefine `\end` to look forwards as above for _your_ code, bu that isn't quite the same

Answer (score 2):

Longer code than David's, but shows how to do it in a more abstract way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,listings}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newcheckcommand}{mm}
 {
  \andrea_new_check_command:Nn #1 { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_andrea_prefix_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \andrea_new_check_command:Nn #1 #2
 {
  \cs_if_exist:NTF #1
   { Damn! } % probably a better message is needed
   { \andrea_def_check_command:Nn #1 { #2 } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \andrea_def_check_command:Nn #1 #2
 {
  \cs_new:Npn #1 { \andrea_check:N #1 }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_andrea_prefix_tl { \cs_to_str:N #1 @ }
  \keys_set:nn { andrea/check } { default = {} }
  \keys_set:nn { andrea/check } { #2 }
 }
\keys_define:nn { andrea/check }
 {
  unknown .code:n = \cs_new:cpn { \l_andrea_prefix_tl \l_keys_key_tl } { #1 } ,
  default .code:n = \cs_gset:cpn { \l_andrea_prefix_tl default } { #1 } ,
 }
\cs_new:Npn \andrea_check:N #1
 {
  \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF \begin
   {
    \andrea_exec:NNn #1
   }
   {
    \use:c { \cs_to_str:N #1 @ default }
   }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \andrea_exec:NNn #1 #2 #3
 {
  % #2 is \begin, #3 is the environment's name
  \cs_if_exist:cTF { \cs_to_str:N #1 @ #3 }
   {
    \use:c { \cs_to_str:N #1 @ #3 }
   }
   {
    \use:c { \cs_to_str:N #1 @ default }
   }
  #2{#3} % put back the \begin{...}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcheckcommand{\foo}{
  lstlisting = \texttt{lstlisting} comes next,
  quotation  = \texttt{quotation} comes next,
  default    = I don't know what to do
}

\begin{document}
\foo
\begin{lstlisting}
x
\end{lstlisting}

\foo
\begin{center}
y
\end{center}

\foo
\begin{quotation}
z
\end{quotation}

\foo xxxx
\begin{lstlisting}
t
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the call `\newcheckcommand{\foo}{...}` a set of macros is defined; the only known key is `default`; if it's not set in the argument, there will be nothing executed, because the `default` macro is initialized to empty.

Comment: The implementation of `xparse/expl3` codind looks very nice by the way, certainly the +1 is deserved, but now I really do not know what to accept because both answers are detailed, exaustive and appropriate (why there isn't a two-acceptable answer?)`:-(`

Comment: @AndreaL. The basic idea is the same as David's.

Comment: Now that two main options have been shown to me, I think it's necessary to accept the first answer (even if I think that both can deserve +25), without saying that yours isn't important to my purposes (thank you for your time).